Getting the status code of 2000 URLs and storing them as a dictionary output in a fast way
I want to get the status code of 2000 urls. I want to store the status code of the url as a dictionary key and the value being the url itself. I also want to do this as quickly as possible. I've seen stuff about async and ThreadPoolExecutor but I don't know how to use any of them yet. How could I solve this problem efficiently?
Here's what I have tried:
import requests 


def check_urls(list_of_urls):
    
    result = {"200": [], "404": [], "anything_else": []}
    
    for url in list_of_urls:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                result["200"].append(url)
            elif response.status_code == 404:
                result["404"].append(url)
            else:
                result["anything_else"].append((url, f"HTTP Error {response.status_code}"))
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            result["anything_else"] = ((url, e))
    
    return result 

Is there any way to improve this code by making it faster to process 2000 URLs? I have tried requests.head but it's not accurate.

What about splitting the list into parts and run the scripts with the partial lists simultaneously? Does it speed it up? You can write a script which generates the scripts and then runs them each on its own. The system will take care about distributing the load and you don't need to learn how to cope with Python libraries providing this basic system feature.

What about using a shell script and store the results to a file? No need for Python. You have the list of URLs anyway already as lines in a text file, right? So a shell script will be perfect for such simple purpose.

let's assume that you have all urls stored in a list:
URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://nonexistant-subdomain.python.org/']

Then you can use any of this two solutions:
Solution 1 - multiprocessing
You may use library concurrent for multi-thread execution. I would also recommend to check library documentation - it has a very neat example that is very close to your case (https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)
import concurrent.futures
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import requests

def get_url_status_code(url):
    # Retrieve a single page and return it's status code
    try:      
        response = requests.get(url, timeout = 10))
        return response.status_code
    except:
        return 404


# As an input to multiprocessing we need to give number of parallel threads to create
# Usually it is 2 times number of cores
n_threads = 2 * cpu_count()
print (f"Count threads available - {n_threads}")


# you need to use 'with' statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly after finishing jobs
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_threads) as executor:

    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    # - to send a job into the thread pool we use executor.submit
    # - usually to distinct the jobs you match them with input parameters (`url`) 
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(get_url_status_code, url): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        status_code = future.result()
        print(url, status_code)

Solution 2 - async
Unfortunately requests library doesn't support async calls thus you need to improvise a bit.
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def fetch_url(session, url:str):
    try:
        response = await session.get(url, timeout=10)
        return response.status
    except:
        return 404
    

async def async_aiohttp_get_all(urls, cookies):

    # context is required to correctly close async connections on errors
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(cookies=cookies) as session:
        result =  await asyncio.gather(*[
            fetch_url(session, url) for url in urls
        ])
        return result


# asyncio.run triggers execution of async coroutines
results = asyncio.run(async_aiohttp_get_all(URLS, None))

# print response status codes
for i, url in enumerate(URLS):
    print(url, results[i])

