How can I make my streamlit program run faster
# Get amazon product names
def scrape_product_names(asins,csv_path='product_names.csv'):
    product_mapping = {}
    for asin in asins:
        url = f"https://www.amazon.com/dp/{asin}"
        response = requests.get(url, data=None, headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        product_title = soup.find("span", {"id": "productTitle"})
        if product_title:
            product_name = product_title.get_text().strip()
            product_name = product_name.split('|')[0].strip()
            product_mapping[asin] = product_name
        else:
            product_mapping[asin] = asin
    return product_mapping

This is the function that I run to get product name from amazon website, but I found that only few name found only and it taking a longer time for running. Is there any recommendation?
Same way I trying to scape image but only few image can got.
Try to get all the product name.

Speed depends on computing power, which you probably already know. That said, scraping can be slow. Especially if you run it on your own machine and the machine is not very powerful. Not knowing more about your computing setup it is hard to say anything more.
GoogleColab provides computing power. Last but not least,  please check whether you are legally allowed to scrape and use the website data from Amazon. The data may be proprietary.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You should break your function into two steps: step1) gather and download all urls and temporary save them as html files; step2) use BS to process outputs. Usually the longest part is getting data from many URLs using requests. Check this topic on how could you speed up downloading data from URLs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78412990/getting-the-status-code-of-2000-urls-and-storing-them-as-a-dictionary-output-in/ So your option is either multiprocessing (X5-10 times speed) or async (X 100 times speed)

Also be aware that most probably your IP will be banned by Amazon if you'll start parsing a lot and in a big volumes.

@JohnnyCheesecutter Okay thank for give this suggestion. I will try out

@JohnnyCheesecutter But is there anyway to retrive all the information form Amazon. This scrape function only get few item from website only. I thinking to use API but I not sure where should i get it from.

@Simone Yep my device could be slower when running huge data. I think unable to run in google collab since I using vsc to run the streamlit progrmam. How to check for whether i legal?

Check the terms & condition section of Amazon. There it will tell you what data you can use / process how.
